# Was 1993 "Stealth Warriors" based on a Marvel property or set in the Marvel universe?

Tags: marvel

[The Wikipedia page for unproduced Marvel series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unproduced_television_projects_based_on_Marvel_Comics#Stealth_Warriors) mentions a 1993 production named *Stealth Warriors* in its Live Action section.

> In November 1993, Rick Ungar was developing Stealth Warriors for Marvel Comics.

[The article linked for reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20140629120645/http://www.highbeam.com/doc/1G1-14701883.html) describes it as an "original animated series".

> Former Marvel Entertinment [sic] chief Rick Ungar will head new division concentrating on original animated series, including upcoming 'Stealth Warriors'

Unfortunately, any details from that article were locked behind a paywall, and the site no longer exists. I did a bit of poking around, but couldn't find anything. Was this story based on a particular Marvel property? Set in the universe? Simply being bankrolled by Marvel?

Comment: Never heard of any property titled 'Stealth Warriors' within Marvel's comics line, and the language used [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140629120645/http://www.highbeam.com/doc/1G1-14701883.html) indicates that Ungar was responsible for developing original properties, while Avi Arad was responsible for developing established properties.

Comment: Well, a little factoid that might give you some context. Batman: The Animated Series (or Batman: TAS) originally aired on the Fox Kids block from 1992 to 1995. It was very successful and groundbreaking animated series and a far cry from the 60s and 80s toycentric animated shows. I guess that Marvel wanted to get some of that action with their own stealthy heroes.

Comment: "Original" usually means "not based on an existing property", so I doubt it was.

Comment: A thin connection, but Brentford Television Funnies Inc, held trademarks for a (now abandoned) ongoing animated show "Stealth Warriors of The Red Pyramid". They also trademarks for Biker Mie From Mars, another New World Animation original. This would point to the show being an actual original concept. https://trademarks.justia.com/owners/brentwood-television-funnies-inc-549437/

Comment: It appears that Mike Kaluta was involved with the character design. I have tried contacting him via his website on the off-chance he'll reply.

Comment: I'd be happy with answers indicating that it was intended to be entirely original, but set in a Marvel universe, or that it was entirely original and just something that Marvel was looking to invest in. I've revised the question to indicate as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to have been an original concept for an animated TV show.

On the artists [Mike Kaluta's Biographical Sketch page](http://www.kaluta.com/pages/bio/bio.html) under 1993 on his personal website, he mentions the following about a planned Marvel Entertainment show:

> I design the Characters and Aircraft for Stealth Warriors of the Red Pyramid, a Saturday AM Cartoon attempt from Marvel Entertainment. The idea is to produce a 2 1/2 minute teaser to convince the bigwigs to produce 30 of the cartoons. As of NOW, nothing happening

The fact that Mike Kaluta states he designed the characters points to this being an original concept for animation.

I contacted Mr Kaluta via email. Copy of email sent:

> Hello Mr Kaluta,
>
> A question on the Science Fiction & Fantasy StackExchange forum has recently come up about a project I believe you were involved in back in 1993, "Stealth Warriors of The Red Pyramid".
>
> I hope you don't mind me contacting you directly like this, but I was hoping if you were able to confirm if this was a completely original concept/characters or if it was based on existing Marvel properties/comics.

Mr Kaluta kindly replied with this concise response:

> Nothing to do with Marvel.
>
> Thanks,
> Michael

This would indicate that the show was being produced by  [Marvel Productions/New World Animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Productions) a subsidiary of Marvel Entertainment Group, but a purely original concept and nothing to do with other Marvel properties or wider universe.

**Edit**:
Mr Kaluta has kindly followed up on his original response with more information.

> Just to flesh out the Stealth Warriors of the Red Pyramid project a touch: It came through the Marvel Studios animation office in LA, but wasn’t a Marvel project and wasn’t based on anything in Marvel’s Massive Idea Hoard. The same team responsible for the successful animation TV series “Biker Mice From Mars” was involved in the project, as far as designs and any writing/ideas etc. I was called in as a special concept design hand.
>
> Alas for the fun, "Stealth Warriors of the Red Pyramid" never really got off the drawing board.
>
> If the forum would care to see some of the concept sketches, say the word. I can also get in touch with the Director/Ramrod of the project and see if he’s open to blabbing away on those lost days if that would be of any interest.

Comment: Thank you. That settles my curiosity.

Comment: I don't suppose you related to Mr. Kaluta that we would indeed be interested in such concept sketches? :)